# How to covert the result /bin/date "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S" into seconds?

Tags: bash, date, environment-variables

How can I convert a date variable to seconds?

I have a variable called CDATE defined like this:

```
CDATE=$(/bin/date +"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

CDATE example output: "2012-12-12 12:12:12"

I would like to convert this to time in seconds and save it in another variable.

Comment: What do you mean _I need CDATE_? Do you want to overwrite the variable?

Comment: For example CDATE variable store 2012:12:12 12:12:12 .     I want to convert this result in seconds and stored in another variable.

Answer (score 3):

On Linux:

```
CDATE=$(date "+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
SECONDS=$(date -d "$CDATE" +%s)
```

On Mac:

```
CDATE=$(date "+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
SECONDS=$(date -j -f "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S" "$CDATE" +%s)
```

And the content of the two variables is (in both cases):

```
$ echo "$CDATE"
2015-04-04 16:24:41

$ echo "$SECONDS"
1428157497
```

Comment: This may not matter from a practical point of view, but the two variables contain different points of time, strictly speaking.

Comment: No, because the second call to `date` just converts the string in `$CDATE` to seconds since 1970-01-01, no new date is generated (just as in your solution).

Comment: Er, yes, I may have stopped reading in the middle of the second line :-)

Answer (score 2):

```
x=($(date +"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %s"))
CDATE="${x[0]} ${x[1]}"
secs="${x[2]}"       # seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC
echo $CDATE
echo $secs
```

Output:

```
2015-04-04 14:13:08
1428149588
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are not charged for CPU time, then I  would call `date` twice to make it more readable:

```
# get the timestamp:
timestamp=$( date +"%s" )

# format it:
CDATE=$( date -d @"$timestamp" +"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S" )

echo "$CDATE"
echo "$timestamp"
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way:

```
source  <(date +"CDATE='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S' EPOCH='%s'")
```

Example:

```
tiago@dell:/tmp$ source  <(date +"CDATE='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S' EPOCH='%s'")
tiago@dell:/tmp$ echo "cdate:$CDATE epoch:$EPOCH"
cdate:2015-04-05 12:39:58 epoch:1428233998
```